# netstat show port number instead of process name

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, netstat

I want to see which port, e.g. postgresql is listening on, so I use:

`netstat -l`

But that is trying to be clever and prints the process name instead of the port:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:31416                 *:*                     LISTEN
```

How can I determine which port any process is listening on with netstat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`netstat` is translating the (default) port to the service name, it gets this mapping from `/etc/services` file.

So, you can get the port from `/etc/services`:

```
grep '^postgresql' /etc/services
```

Or better add the `-n` option to `netstat` to prevent any (host, port, hostname) resolution and post the output in numerics:

```
netstat -nl
```

You can limit the search interface by adding `-t` option for only showing listening TCP sockets (similarly `-u` for UDP, `-x` for UNIX domain sockets):

```
netstat -nlt
```

You can also use any standard text processing tool over the result to get desired stuffs only.